# Why are large scale structures isotropic in the Ising model?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, symmetry, ising-model

I have at least a qualitative understanding of why the critical state of the Ising model is scale invariant, by arguments to do with renormalisation, which I understand only very roughly.

However, in addition to being invariant to changes in scale, the large-scale patterns at the critical point are also invariant with respect to rotations, even though the use of a (square) lattice makes the model anisotropic at the microscopic level. For that matter, the phase separated 'blob' pattern that forms when the Ising model is quenched also seems to be rotationally invariant.

Can someone offer me an explanation (intuitive or technical, or preferably both) for why one should expect large-scale structures in this type of model to be rotationally invariant?

Comment: What do you mean by "the phase separated 'blob' pattern that forms when the Ising model is quenched"? Do you mean the shape of the droplet of one phase immersed inside the other, when the magnetization is fixed at a value between $m^*$ and $-m^*$? If yes, then this shape is not rotation invariant, since the surface tension is not and the shape is obtained by the Wulff construction. It is true, however, that (properly rescaled) this shape converges to a disk as $\beta\downarrow\beta_c$.

Comment: Note that the latter result has been only proved in dimension $2$, and there it results from the fact that surface tension becomes isotropic in this limit, for very much the same reason the 2d random walk converges to Brownian motion.

Comment: @YvanVelenik no, I mean the pattern that arises if you start at a high temperature and then rapidly drop it to below the critical temperature, then run it for a longish time (using e.g. Metropolis updating) but not for long enough to reach equilibrium. If you do that you get a pattern with a characteristic scale, which looks isotropic to the eye. Though I guess it might not really be isotropic, because it probably also depends on the surface tension. (Your comments were very helpful.)

Comment: Does this happen with other numerical relaxation schemes, say Wolff, or is it truly dynamics independent? I think there should be a relation with what @YvanVelenik was saying about the "canonical ensemble" as the pattern you describe might only occur "near equilibrium". I have little knowledge of the formal mathematics, but I think you could perhaps write the problem in terms of Ricci flow or a discretized version (if one exists) and ask about the symmetry properties of the resulting shape (should not be difficult if you are willing to go to continuum mean field/phase field numerics of Ising)

Comment: @alarge whether it's dynamics independent is difficult to say, as I don't have any Wolff algorithm code lying around to test it with. My intuition says I could probably come up with some crazy dynamical scheme that would result in obviously anisotropic quenching though, so I suspect it isn't.

Comment: There is actually a [proof](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/037596017690219X) that the spin-spin correlation is rotationally symmetric at the critical temperature for a 2d square lattice Ising model.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know that this qualifies as a full answer, but the “intuitive” answer would be that on large enough scales, the details of the lattice won't matter: If you look from far enough away (conversely, the lattice parameter is sufficiently small), it will look like a continuum.

In this picture, you would expect large-scale structures to be fully rotationally invariant, but not smaller ones.  On the other hand, a similar statement would hold for the scale invariance.

Incidentally, when you say “seems to be rotationally invariant”, do you have any analytical or numerical evidence for that?  Once I looked at the correlation function, and I did see (numerically) that it was more or less circular.

UPDATE: Here are those correlation functions.  I have been a bit reluctant to post them because (a) it does not really add anything as to *why* the correlations behave this way, and (b) I made them years ago for a course project, so the data (produced with the Swendsen-Wang algorithm) are maybe not as “safe”, and the plots not as nice as you would expect in a publication.  With this caveat, I will go ahead and post them anyway.

What to look for: At $T \gtrless T_c$, the (connected!) correlation function decays quickly, at $T=T_c$ it is far-ranged.  The isolines show how circularly symmetric the correlation function becomes at longer distance, while at short distance (in the high-$T$ plot) you can still see the lattice.  (Note the different scales on the plots.)

[image: connected correlation function $G_c(x,y)$ at $T<T_c$]
[image: connected correlation function $G_c(r)$ at $T<T_c$]

---

[image: connected correlation function $G_c(x,y)$ at $T=T_c$]
[image: connected correlation function $G_c(r)$ at $T>T_c$]

---

[image: connected correlation function $G_c(x,y)$ at $T>T_c$]
[image: connected correlation function $G_c(r)$ at $T>T_c$]

Comment: I really appreciate the answer, but the thing is, for someone who plays with cellular automata for a living, it's really quite remarkable that the lattice details don't matter on large enough scales. For "most systems" that isn't the case, and the lattice anisotropy is inherited by the large-scale structures. There must be some special mechanism that makes the lattice behave like a continuum in models with the structure of the Ising model, and I'm curious about what that is. For scale invariance I can sort of see it, but isotropy still seems a mystery to me.

Comment: I'm afraid I didn't mean anything formal by "seems to be rotationally invariant" - I just meant that when looking at high-resolution images from simulations, I can't see any straight edges aligned with the lattice, or any other tell-tale clues that suggest anisotropy.

Comment: Well, if you “play with cellular automata for a living” (nice job description, btw) you probably have more in-depth knowledge about this than me.  However, I would argue that a belief that lattice models can approximate the continuum on large scales is quite pervasive in physics (e.g., lattice QCD, and wasn't there a lattice model for the liquid-gas transition?).  Conversely, real solids and liquids can be quite successfully described using continuum models.

Comment: I guess the evidence is that sometimes the lattice becomes irrelevant in the large-scale limit, and sometimes it doesn't. Diffusion and the Ising model become isotropic on large scales, but (to pick the first arbitrary example I found with an animation on Wikipedia), [Brian's Brain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brian%27s_Brain) doesn't. In the case of diffusion I have some understanding of why the lattice anisotropy washes out, but for the Ising model I don't. I suspect the answer is quite non-trivial. (Merry Christmas by the way!)